# NSFetchRequest on NSOrderedSet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a core data entity called Entry, which has an one-many relationship with entities called Media, which are in an ordered set. I want to run an NSFetchRequest to request a batch size of them, so I can go through them and don't have to load all of them into memory at once. I want to go through them in the order they're in the ordered set though. How can I get them to be in that order?

Answer (score 0):

The best route to go is using an `NSFetchedResultsController` when you are concerned about memory management when fetching Core Data entities. It will automatically only fetch the objects that you need and minimize the memory footprint.

By fetching all your relevant objects of your ordered set, they should already be in the expected order.